# How to create java web form with spring, bootsrap, javascript that calls java method?

Tags: java, spring, http, web, localhost

this is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm really confused..

I'm new with java and very confused at this moment. I'm planning to create a java web service with spring that handles a webform and a portable scanner device. I get this project for my first in new workplace but I can't move on. I don't know what are the neccesery steps to succeed.

What I want from the Application running step-by-step:

1. Open in an executable file that
2. Open a new browser window on localhost and shows a form
3. Filling out form with input fields, checkbox items, dropdown list, 
   commentbox,
4. AND Option for file upload from local and/or call startScan() java method.

startScan() = take photo from device and saves it to project's root folder and rename it as formatted date: "yymmdd_hhmmss"

5. submitButton()
6. onSubmitButton() the form data should be saved in database that
   later i can download as xml

I have read lot of blogs and watch tutorials but that causes me confused. JPA? Hibernate? REST? REACT? I would like to create a very simple app that can display the form on window browser that is easy to access with bootsrap.

What is the neccesery toolset for doing this as simple as possible? 
mysql? postgresql? which of these I can implement, what should i install locally?

If I could came out from back end to front that would be awesome..

Goal: Create a localhost database system that handles the form and scanner device method in a fancy css view.

Now, I'm using eclipse with spring. What are the neccesery dependencies? what are the local requirements for this kind of project? Please, help me with any advices..

I am very grateful for everything
Thank you in advance

Comment: I will recommend to create REST API with spring-boot. Spring boot provides almost all you need int backend side out of the box (JPA, Hibernate, REST), for database both Postgres and Mysql are good. Having backend with REST API will allow you write any amount and any kind of frontend you want (web, ios, android, ...). Then you will create frontend calling this REST API with REACT as you said.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I designed something similar, a simple two-page web application with login functionality and application main page that supports database operations and scanning functionality.

I would recommend you to go step-by-step since documentation is also as important, to be able to clearly visualize the project objectives, to know the constraints before-hand, make modifications on-the-fly and as a reference for your peers.

As a newbie with Java development, these are some basic steps and links which I feel would be helpful:

1. Project Scope Document (Web based tool: [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/))
2. Project Plan Document
3. Site Map (Web based tool: [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/))
4. Front-end Wireframing (Web-based tool: [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.cloud/))
5. Back-end Wireframing (Microsoft Excel)
6. Back-end Flow chart (Web-based tool: [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/))
7. Front-end development (Technologies: HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap 3, JavaScript; Tool: [Brackets](http://brackets.io/))
8. Back-end development (Technologies: PL/SQL or MySQL, Java, JDBC, Servlet, JSP, JSTL; Tools: [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), [JBoss Studio](https://developers.redhat.com/products/devstudio/hello-world/?tcUser=null%20null&tcDownloadFileName=devstudio-11.1.0.GA-installer-standalone.jar&tcRedirect=5000&tcSrcLink=https://developers.redhat.com/download-manager/content/origin/files/sha256/e5/e53e8075968b4bff6019650aa54f716422db9c3a0193003c4af6cc3a0a6d6def/devstudio-11.1.0.GA-installer-standalone.jar&p=JBoss%20Developer%20Studio&pv=11.1.0&tcDownloadURL=https://access.cdn.redhat.com/content/origin/files/sha256/e5/e53e8075968b4bff6019650aa54f716422db9c3a0193003c4af6cc3a0a6d6def/devstudio-11.1.0.GA-installer-standalone.jar?_auth_))
9. Integrating Scanner (Third-party Java APIs)

Technology Stack: This is a simple and very generalized stack preference. You could customize it according to your needs. 
Helpful Links on getting started: [Java Web Terminology](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaWebTerminology/article.html), [JBoss Hello-world tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.1.Final/en/GettingStartedGuide/html/jsp_application.html), [Simple Java web application](https://o7planning.org/en/10285/create-a-simple-java-web-application-using-servlet-jsp-and-jdbc)

Tools: Draw.io and Balsamiq are easy to use web based tools. You could use Bootstrap to make a quick fancy front-end. Brackets is a nice front-end code-editor supporting live-previews. SQL Developer is a wonderful tool if you're using Oracle SQL. JBoss Eclipse IDE has in-built application server which you can use for testing on localhost.

Note: All tools and technologies listed here are either free or include a trial version.

Hope that helps!